# How do I let users send an e-mail from a form in my Flash website?

Tags: html, flash, forms

I’ve just started working as a Flash web designer. Right now I’m making one Flash website.

I’m making this website in Flash, and to upload the web content I’m using an HTML file. I’ve also created a “Contact Us” page on this site. On that page I’ve made one small form with five tags. At the end I’ve put two buttons — the first is “Reset”, and the second is “Send”. The reset button works properly, but when I click on the send button then it’s not working.

So my question is if I have to send email from a form, then which script do I have to use? Please help me to complete this site.

Thank you and kind regards

Comment: Post your actionscript before we can help you.

Comment: Your form on the “Contact Us” page: is it an HTML form, or is it in your Flash file?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/flash_php_email.htm

Kirupa has great tutorials for Flash actionscript coding.

Edit: Always look at the actionscript code if it's AS2 or AS3!